# Left and Right Menu - Position Fix and middle content should be scrollable

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am making a page where I am using left and Right menu which should be position fix and middle content should be scrollable and should be behind the menus I tried below HTML and CSS but getting error.

while I am give right menu position: fixed its coming right side but on position:relative its working fine.

your early reply would appreciated..

```css
.mainBody {
  display: block;
  border: 0px solid #000;
  max-height: 100%;
  min-height: 500px;
  position: relative;
}

.sidebar-left {
  border: 0 solid #004087;
  min-height: auto;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 30;
}

.pull-left {
  float: left !important;
}

contentright {
  margin-left: 0;
  width: 200px;
}

.contentrightStyle {
  height: 100%;
  padding-right: 0 !important;
  width: auto;
}

.sidebar-right {
  border: 0 solid #004087;
  min-height: auto;
  position: fixed;
}

.pull-right {
  float: right !important;
}

.contentleft {
  height: 100%;
  padding-left: 23px !important;
  width: 200px;
}

.contentleft {
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: -25px;
  width: 266px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainBody" style="">

  <div id="sidePanelLeft" class="pull-left sidebar-left">
    <a class="toggler" data-whois="toggler" id="openerleft" style="">
      <i id="toggleImgleft" class="glyphicon glyphiconStyle" style=""></i>
    </a>
    <div id="contentright" class='visible contentrightStyle' style="">
    </div>

  </div>

  <div id="" class='pull-right sidebar-right' style="">
    <a class="toggler" data-whois="toggler" id="opener" style="">
      <i id="toggleImg" class="glyphicon glyphiconStyle" style=""></i>
    </a>
    <div id="contentleft" class='visible contentleftStyle' style="width: auto;">
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="ScrollableContent">
    th tht jjtkj kl jtlktjkler th tht jjtkj
  </div>

  <div class="clearfix"></div>


</div>
```

here is screenshot for reference where my right menu overlapping on left menu when I give position:fixed to right menu..

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpGSi.png)

Comment: I using left and right menu and for that I am giving position fix to my left menu and right menu but right menu is overlapping on left menu please see my screenshot which I shared now..

Comment: Use `flex` instead of `float`. `float` is evil and can make you crazy.

Answer (score 0):

if you give position:fixed it will by default stay with `left:0` and `top:0`

you should specify `right:0` on the fixed `right` menu

see below ( red is only with position:fixed;blue has also right:0; )

also when using `position:fixed` , `float:left` or `float:right` is useless, the item with position:fixed only aligns depending on the values you set to it's position top,right,bottom,left and by default it has `top:0;left:0`

```css
div {
 position:fixed;
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
}
.test1 {
 background:red;
}
.test2 {
 right:0;
 background:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="test1">

</div>
<div class="test2">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.mainBody {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /*border: 0px solid #000;*/
  max-height: 100%;
  min-height: 500px;
  background-color: '#000';
}

.sidebar-left, .ScrollableContent, .sidebar-right {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.sidebar-left{
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainBody" >
    <div class="sidebar-left">
      <a class="toggler" data-whois="toggler" id="openerleft">
        Menu 1
      </a>
      <div id="contentright" class='visible contentrightStyle'>
       <a href="#">Menu2</a>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="ScrollableContent">
      <p>Your scrollable content</p>
    </div>


    <div id="" class=' sidebar-right'>
      <a class="toggler" data-whois="toggler" id="opener">
        <i id="toggleImg" class="glyphicon glyphiconStyle"></i>Right menu
      </a>
      <div id="contentleft" class='visible contentleftStyle'>
      </div>

    </div>


  </div>
```